# how to spread the tables over whole page

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I generate EER Diagram by MySQL Workbench:

[image]

As you can see all tables placed in one place and manually to spread them all is very annoying job.

Is there a way to automatically spread them over whole page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the 'Arrange' menu, select 'Autolayout'.